# A question related to convergence property of proximal point algorithm

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, fixed-point-theorems

Let us consider a simple convex optimization problem
\begin{align}
\operatorname{minimize}_{x} & \quad \theta(x) + f(x), \tag{$\heartsuit$}
\end{align}
where both $\theta(x) $ and $f(x)$ are convex functions; $f(x)$ is smooth but $\theta(x)$ is not necessarily smooth.

For solving $(\heartsuit)$, the $k$-th iteration of the proximal point algorithm begins with a given $x^k$, and renders a new iterate $x^{k+1}$ via the recursion
\begin{align}
x^{k+1} = \operatorname{argmin}_x  \theta(x) + f(x) + \frac{r}{2} \| x - x^k \|_2^2.
\end{align}

As shown in the literature (see, e.g., slide#9-10 in [[1](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/%7Ehebma/Talk/Simple_Power.pdf)]), one could show the nice contraction property as
\begin{align}
\|x^{k+1} - x^\star\|^2 \leq \|x^{k} - x^\star\|^2 - \|x^{k} - x^{k+1}\|^2.
\end{align}

---

Now my questions are, if one shows $\exists \alpha, 0 < \alpha \leq 1$
\begin{align}
{\color{red}{\alpha}} \|x^{k+1} - x^\star\|^2 \leq \|x^{k} - x^\star\|^2 - \|x^{k} - x^{k+1}\|^2.
\end{align}

> Does the above not show convergence still? In my eyes, it does. Please correct me if I am wrong. Please enlighten me.

> If you agree it does show convergence, then how to interpret such a contraction?

> Should both terms $\|x^{k+1} - x^\star\|^2$ and $\|x^{k} - x^\star\|^2$ have equal weights? In other words, should $\alpha$ factor exist on both terms $\|x^{k+1} - x^\star\|^2$ and $\|x^{k} - x^\star\|^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inequality alone does not show convergence. It only implies boundedness of $(x_k)$ and $\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|\to0$. Note that a constant sequence $x_k=x^0\ne x^*$ also satisfies the inequality.

If the inequality is fulfilled only for some $\alpha\in (0,1)$ then not much can be said: $x^*=0$ and $x_k = \left(\frac{2}{1+\alpha}\right)^k$ satisfy the inequality but $(x_k)$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I see that this inequality alone cannot show convergence. 

I am sorry for being slow and do not figure out how you came up with $x_k = \left(\frac{2}{(1+\alpha)}\right)^k$ ?

Let  $\beta = 1 - \alpha$, then the above inequality can be written as $\| x^{k+1} - x^\star\|^2 \leq  \| x^{k} - x^\star\|^2 \!+\! \beta \| x^{k+1} - x^\star\|^2 - \|  x^{k} - x^{k+1} \|^2 $. Under what conditions I can show that $x^k$ is bounded? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I tried to figure out when the inequality holds as equation.

Comment: May be I raise another question on boundedness and accept your answer